# Fastest way of getting a list of all the words and its similars in a Word2vec model?

Tags: python, word2vec

I have a recommendation Word2vec model built in Python. I can check each product top similars using wv.most_similar(). But I'm struggling to find a fast way to iterate over the list of products and get each the similars for each one of them.

Is there a way of getting all the products similars? Or would you recommend a fast way of doing it?

Comment: Are you using the Gensim library? How many tokens are in the model? Are you trying to find every single token's most-similar neighbors? Did you have any problems trying just iterating over every token, and calling `most_similar()` for each, other than the fact it was slower than you'd like?